# Invalid map key type "identifier"

Tags: dictionary, go

Below type definition:

```
type tuple struct{
    key string
    value string
}

type identifier struct{
    metricName tuple
    labels []tuple
}

type value struct{
    timestamp int64
    timeSeriesValue float64  
}

type DataModel map[identifier][]value
```

---

gives error: `invalid map key type identifier`

`struct` type can be a key in Go

Is `identifier` type not comparable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map key types must be comparable, and while you're right that struct types are allowed to be map keys, they still need to be comparable.  Structs are only comparable if their fields are comparable, and since slices are not comparable, `identifier` is not a comparable type.  Thus, it can't be a map key type.

The Go spec spells this out pretty clearly in these two sections:

- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types
- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators

---

Your original question was about `identifier` not being comparable and being an invalid map key type.  But as far as your follow-up question about what to do about it:

It's hard to say the best way to proceed based on just the code you have here, but I'll note that pointer values are comparable, so it may work well for you to define DataModel as

```
type DataModel map[*identifier][]value
```

Comment: Slice is mutable type, so map keys cannot be mutable types, yes, but,But, how to overcome this issue?

Comment: It's hard to say the best way to proceed based on just the code you have here, but I'll note that pointer values are comparable, so it may work for you to define DataModel as `type DataModel map[*identifier][]value`.

Comment: `type Labels *[]tuple` and then `labels Labels`?

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a great approach.

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to be happy with `*[]tuple`, but it's hard to understand what exactly you hope to achieve by putting the labels in the key of a map.  would different identifiers have the same `[]tuple`, thus it's address being relevant?  If the idea is that the identifier name and labels' values would be comparable, just because two `[]tuple`s don't have the same address, doesn't mean they don't have the same labels.  I get the feeling this isn't the right organization of your data for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

> The comparison operators == and != must be fully defined for operands of the key type; thus the key type must not be a function, map, or slice

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types

So, it does not compile because a slice is a part of the struct used as a key.